# Naive Bayes classification for multivalued marginal

Tags: probability, bayesian, classification, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

| x | y | z | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

The dataset in the table above consisting of boolean variables x,
y and z and a single boolean output variable C. I want to use naive Bayes classifier.

I need to specify the value of (C = 1|x = 1, y = 1, z = 0)
I couldn't be sure which equation i should use.

First equation:
$$
P(C = 1 | x = 1, y = 1, z = 0) = \frac{P(C = 1) \cdot P(x = 1 | C = 1) \cdot P(y = 1 | C = 1) \cdot P(z = 0 | C = 1)}{P(x = 1) \cdot P(y = 1) \cdot P(z = 0)}
$$

Second equation:
$$
P(C = 1 | x = 1, y = 1, z = 0) = \frac{P(C = 1) \cdot P(x = 1 | C = 1) \cdot P(y = 1 | C = 1) \cdot P(z = 0 | C = 1)}{P(x = 1, y = 1, z = 0)}
$$

We assume attributes are conditionally independent in naive bayes. So i thought first one is true but some resources say second one is true.

Which equation is correct for this problem? Why?